# Merge two matrices using awk

Tags: unix, matrix, awk

Is it possible to do the following using awk?

I have two matrices, for example;

File 1, two variables

```
1 red big
2 blue small
3 yellow big
4 grey big
5 black small
```

File 2, two variables:

```
1 yellow 17
2 red 22
3 blue 15
4 violet 32
```

And I would like to obtain:

```
1 red big 22
2 blue small 15
3 yellow big 17
4 grey big
5 black small
6 violet 32
```

I tried with this one: `awk 'NR==FNR {h[$2] = $3; next} {print $1,$2,$3,h[$2]}' File 2 File 1 > File 3` although it does not include the variables of the second file.

Comment: so you want to add keys present in file2 but not in file1 to end after all lines of file1? try `awk 'NR==FNR {h[$2] = $3; next} {print $0,h[$2]; delete h[$2]} END{for (k in h){print ++FNR, k, h[k]}}' file2 file1` ...

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code does the half job. Output of your code is like this:

```
1 red big 22 
2 blue small 15 
3 yellow big 17 
4 grey big   
5 black small
```

What you are not including is the entries existed in file2 but are missing from file1. Give a try to this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$2] = $3; next}{print $1,$2,$3,h[$2];delete h[$2]}END{for (i in h) print i,h[i]}' file2 file1
```

In this case the output will be:

```
1 red big 22 
2 blue small 15 
3 yellow big 17 
4 grey big   
5 black small
violet 32
```

You need then decide what number you will apply in front of "orphan" entries. 
You can either apply 4 violet 32 since 4 is the $1 in the file2 , or you can apply a global incremental count in all entries like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$2] = $3; next}{print ++c,$2,$3,h[$2];delete h[$2]}END{for (i in h) print ++c,i,h[i]}' file2 file1
```

In this case output will be:

```
1 red big 22 
2 blue small 15 
3 yellow big 17 
4 grey big   
5 black small
6 violet 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one using `join` for joining, `sort` for sorting, process substitution and `nl` for numbering the lines:

```
$ nl <(join -a 1 -a 2 <(cut -d \  -f 2- file1 | sort) <(cut -d \  -f 2- file2|sort))
     1  black small
     2  blue small 15
     3  grey big
     4  red big 22
     5  violet 32
     6  yellow big 17
```